# Why is Mediapipe messing with my sound card?

Tags: mediapipe, stable-diffusion, soundcard, directml

This is an issue when using Stable Diffusion Automatic 1111 DirectML, and the adetailer extension.  It has some Mediapipe options in it.  When those are activated, SD stops generating.  I get a popup about my Creative ASIO device changing.  I have to click OK to move on, which generates a second popup.  After I click OK on that, everything proceeds fine.  Today I reinstalled from scratch.  Now this issue happens every time I start SD.  I'm guessing Mediapipe is doing something with the sound card, and reverting it immediately?  How do I fix this?  The Adetailer devs sent me here.  I use a Sound Blaster Audigy 5/Rx card, and Windows 10.
https://github.com/Bing-su/adetailer
https://github.com/lshqqytiger/stable-diffusion-webui-directml

I have no idea what I can even try.  I used to just not select the Mediapipe options.  Now that's not even an option.[error in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kh6J.jpg)
Message after the error:
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.[05:14<00:00, 12.04s/it]
mediapipe: 1 detected.
15%|██████▌                                    | 2/13 [00:08<00:46,  4.24s/it]